# Controller issue when creating new Play application with Intellij 15

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, playframework

I created a new Play application with Intellij 15.  The play version used was 2.4.2 so I updated it to 2.4.6 following the [migration guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24).  I changed my Application controller to a Java class, but now I'm getting the following error:

```
Class 'Application' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'RequestTimeout()' in 'Controller'
```

Here is what my application controller looks like:

```
package controllers;

import play.api.mvc.Controller;
import play.api.mvc.Result;

public class Application extends Controller {
    public Result index() {
        return ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."));
    }
}
```

I did add the routes generator (`routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator`) to my `build.sbt` as suggested in the Dependency Injection section of the migration guide.

Some final notes:

(1) I created the application as a Scala Play application because IntelliJ did not generate the project correctly when I tried creating it as a Java application with the Play framework, and I want to use sbt anyways.

(2) I noticed that the Scala Application controller was generated as an `object` rather than a `class`, indicating that it was still using static routes; so I'm guessing it has something to do with the dependency injection, but I don't see anything in their documentation other than the steps in the migration guide.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `play.mvc.Controller` instead. In other words, don't use the `api` packages because they are intended to be used only in scala projects. Just change your code to:

```
package controllers;

import play.mvc.Controller; // no .api.
import play.mvc.Result; // no .api.

public class Application extends Controller {
    public Result index() {
        return ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."));
    }
}
```

About your notes:

1. Use [Activator](https://www.lightbend.com/community/core-tools/activator-and-sbt) to create projects and then import them to IDEA.
2. Activator will probably create the project using DI instead of `object` to define controllers. Anyway, the [steps at the migration guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24#Dependency-Injection) suffice to migrate your app.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  And thanks for the tips, I forgot all about Activator.